# Is Eckersley's *Essential English* still in use?

Tags: resources, learning

When I taught myself English a long time ago I used (alongside Assimil's *L'anglais sans peine* and the BBC's *Calling all beginners*) a series of four books,  *Essential English* authored by C.E. Eckersley and published by Longmans.
It was an impressively good set of boooks, with plenty of grammatical  and cultural explanations, presented in a very British witty and amusing style and accompanied by funny but quite relevant cartoons and schematic drawings.

My question is whether English is still taught from these textbooks.
I confess that I was emboldened to ask this question by the mischievous thought that for once you native English speakers would be at a disadvantage to answer it (unless you teach English) as compared to us foreigners ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a particular resource.  Interesting, but not really on topic.

Comment: Also, why a disadvantage?  We can all Google!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be easily answered by a simple search for a single nigh-on-impossible-to-access reference work.

Comment: 'My question is whether English is still taught from these textbooks.' _My_ question is whether 90% of what these textbooks contain is still relevant / accepted as correct.

Comment: Echoing and expanding on @Edwin's comment below (*Please* don't buy it), I think it would be a very *bad* idea to use older textbooks that haven't at least been recently revised. Partly because language itself moves on, but mainly because teachers' *attitudes* to language teaching have moved on. 50 years ago I was probably mainly being taught the rules of language as applicable to writers/speakers from at least 3-4 generations earlier than me. At least today's teachers are only likely to be *one* generation behind the times!

Comment: ... Yeah - it's about time they did a remake of 'West Side Story'. [Did I really just write 'yeah'?]

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: If you have a question, just ask it on main and let me be judge of what my question is. I find your comments  unpleasant and irrelevant.

Comment: @Fumble Fingers: my question is not about a recommendation to buy it.

Comment: @Georges: No, but you did ask whether it would still be used to *teach* English. And my comment was intended to indicate both that I think this is highly unlikely *and* that it would be a bad idea if anyone *was* still using such materials. You've only got to compare modern BBC newscasts (generally considered to be high quality contemporary English) with archive footage from 50 years ago to see that quite a lot has changed (even  in *my* lifetime).

Comment: @Fumblefingers: yes quite a lot has changed in the BBC courses, but in my opinion they have deteriorated. As you know there was much controversy about the BBC decision of no longer resorting to the Queen's English but of using Estuary English and the like. These were political decisions, looked upon positively by a majority to which I imagine you belong. However I have a quite different,  approach, the defense of which this site is not the place. This reinforces my tender feelings for the Eckersley books and their endearing characters, the mute witnesses of a linguistic era forever gone.

Comment: @Georges: I'm not sure the BBC's belated adoption of regional accents (not particularly *Estuary English*) has much bearing on the matter. But it sounds like you and I are probably at opposite ends of the *descriptive* (linguists) and *pro/prescriptive* (grammarians) spectrum. FWIW I'm often ambivalent about things like glottal stops - I use these as often as I use swear words in my "casual" speech (i.e. - a *lot!* :), but if I can unerringly avoid both in "formal" speech I don't see why people at least *partly* paid for their diction can't manage to do the same.

Comment: (Anyway, if we're going to get picky, your cherished books would be a mute witness **to** a bygone age, not **of** it. :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: are you sure you can't be a witness of something? Even if that were so, what is your point? English is not my mother tongue (this is exactly at the heart of my question) and I never claimed that I don't make mistakes. Not making mistakes  is only  my prescriptivist unattainable goal: *il n'est pas nécessaire d'espérer pour entreprendre, ni de réussir pour persévérer*. Finally, just out of curiosity,  in how many foreign languages could you make a conversation in which the worst error would be the use of "witness of" instead of "witness to"?

Comment: @Georges: My apologies. If English isn't your mother tongue then I must admit you have exceptionally good command of it (I didn't register the implications of your first words in the question). I myself can only speak indifferent French and order food & drink in a few other languages, so you win on that score! What I *meant* was simply that, as you imply, we all make mistakes. Please feel free to ask here about *witness to/of* - I doubt there would be much support for *of*, but I don't know everything.

Comment: ...I couldn't resist checking. [A couple of centuries ago](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=witness+of%2Cwitness+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwitness%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwitness%20to%3B%2Cc0) both were equally common, but today it's almost always ***to*** (most of the "atypical" modern instances are probably references to earlier text anyway).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I really appreciate your courteous and graceful comment. Differing on certain academic points doesn't mean being enemies and I certainly feel no such feeling against you! And, yes, I'll follow your suggestion and ask that question on this site!

Comment: Thank *you* for your grace under pressure! I'm now sorry I stole your thunder and looked into the "witness" issue!

Comment: Yes, electronic exchanges are too fast! Anyway, thanks for answering my question before I posted it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems they are out of print. But second-hand copies would appear to be available at a vastly wide range of prices. Book 3, in particular, must be a collectors item at £95! Others are available for pence. Try:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=Essential+English+%2B+Eckersley&rh=n%3A266239%2Ck%3AEssential+English+%2B+Eckersley

Comment: _Please_ don't buy a set.

Comment: Dear WS2, I own and cherish my set but thanks for the information. I encourage everybody to at least look at those books, independently of whether they want to learn from it.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: I find your writing four snarky, aggressive  and  completely  content-free comments as well as  your exhortation not to buy a book you had never heard of  five minutes ago hilarious.

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg: But it's quite all right for you to post a 'mischievous question'? May I ask whether you had the propriety to check on whether or not your question was appropriate for this site before posting? The focus is on modern English usage. I quote: 'Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.

Ask about...

Word choice and usage
Grammar
Etymology (history of words’ development)
Dialect differences
Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology)
Spelling and punctuation'

Comment: ... And my exhortation was to a specific person, not general ... I would never advise people in general to avoid texts in Early Modern English, for example. But quoting examples from them to claim acceptable modern usage would be a misuse. As FF says, "I think it would be a very bad idea to use older textbooks that haven't at least been recently revised...."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth For the avoidance of doubt, I never ever had the slightest intention of buying a set. I was only interested to see if they were still in print.

Comment: @WS (I'm using your first name): I've got to get hold of a copy of McCawley at some point. Everything that John Lawler quotes seems to make total sense (though it can be hard to follow), which is something I can't say even for ACGEL and CGEL. Of course, in 100 years time, some wag will write 'Please don't buy a copy of McCawley, EA4'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As you may have gathered I'm not professionally in  this field. I do this to pass the time, my wife being a crossword and sudoku addict. For family reasons we are spending a lot of time in Mcr. Were in your neck of the woods last night. Ate at a pub in Mossley.